# Why specifically 3 meters above the sky?

Tags: dialogue, three-steps-above-heaven

In [Tre metri sopra il cielo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tre_metri_sopra_il_cielo_(film)) ([IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0388483/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)) aka *Three Steps Above Heaven*, Babi and Hugo are measuring how happy they are.

> Hugo: My happiness reaches Barcelona!
>
> Baby: Mine reaches the sky!
>
> Hugo: Mine goes 3 meters over the sky.

This line is the movie's title, "Three Steps Above Heaven". But what this does mean, specifically? Is this an Italian expression? Or some reference to Hugo's past?

This is the original Italian dialogue [from the book](http://www.editricenord.it/generi/narrativa_generale/tre_metri_sopra_il_cielo_9788842930198.php):

> "Sono felicissima. Non sono mai stata così bene in tutta la mia vita. Tu come stai?"
>
> "Io?" Step l’abbracciò forte fra le braccia. "Sto benissimo."
>
> "Da arrivare a toccare il cielo con un dito?"
>
> Step le sorrise e scosse la testa. "No, non così."
>
> "Come, non così?"
>
> "Molto di più. Almeno tre metri sopra il cielo."

Comment: I have edited the question because it is an Italian book originally. Maybe the question gets better answers on [Italian.se]

Comment: I can tell you that this wasn't an Italian idiom until after the book/film was released.